# What is a good PHP image gallery shopping cart?

Tags: images, php, cms, gallery, shopping-cart

I am building a website and I need to have an image gallery which viewers can use to look at photos.

Furthermore, I want people to be able to click on an image and then purchase prints. Is there a good PHP product that I can purchase to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into PhotoStore as an option,

**[PhotoStore by KTools](http://www.ktools.net/photostore/)** (Commercial, starts at $149 - Lifetime updates)

> PhotoStore is a complete professional solution for selling your
> photography, stock photos, artwork, **prints**, products, videos and other
> digital files. PhotoStore is completely automated including a backend
> management area that allows you to add categories, configure prints,
> upload photos and other files, assign keywords & prices, configure
> website settings, add shipping costs, add tax, create coupons and
> discounts, add site news, manage members, view orders, create photo
> collections and much more.
>
> [image: PhotoStore Hero Image]
>
> [image: PhotoStore backend manager]